# Pandas: How to find the low after a high within a rolling window

Tags: python, pandas, max, min, rolling-computation

For a series of numbers, I am trying to find the low after the high within a rolling window.  I am able to calculate the high within the window, but not the low after it within the same window.  I'm using Pandas and have tried to get the index of the high and use that as some type of reference, but I can't get it to work.

Here is some code to set up the problem:

```
 dates = pd.date_range("20130101", periods=15)
 temps = {'Temperature' :[16, 3, 26, 56, 2, 92, 54, 98, 73, 68, 80, 18, 75, 24, 12]}
 df = pd.DataFrame(temps, index=dates, columns = ['Temperature'])
 df['RollMax'] = df['Temperature'].rolling(5).max()
 # df['Low_After_High'] = ### Lowest value after high has been reached within the window
```

And here is what the output should look like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us do `apply` with `idxmax`

```
df['Low_After_High'] = df.Temperature.rolling(5).apply(lambda x : min(x[pd.Series(x).idxmax():]))
2013-01-01     NaN
2013-01-02     NaN
2013-01-03     NaN
2013-01-04     NaN
2013-01-05     2.0
2013-01-06    92.0
2013-01-07    54.0
2013-01-08    98.0
2013-01-09    73.0
2013-01-10    68.0
2013-01-11    68.0
2013-01-12    18.0
2013-01-13    18.0
2013-01-14    18.0
2013-01-15    12.0
Freq: D, Name: Temperature, dtype: float64
```